# How to set SearchProperty.Add on a parent element of a UITestControl

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have defined a UI test control for a set of toolbars which appears on every screen of a windows application. The search properties for each control on the toolbars is the same on every screen it appears on, with the exception of one.

So in the following example ...

```
UITestControl ControlName = AllUIMaps.ClientMaps.TopBars.Window.Screen.Toolbar_Icon.Toolbar.Button_ChangePassword
```

... the 5th element (`Screen`) accepts a search property of `ControlName` and I could write a `UIMap` for every screen the toolbar appears on. However this seems a little excessive.

Is it possible to change the search properties of the 5th element of the above example (`ControlName = whateverscreenIamon`) so I could then write a helper which is passed the whole `UITestControl` and modifies the .Screen element ?

Answer (score 0):

I have a WpfCustom object in my test project. The class does not have any code to change those search properties and it inherited the WPFCustom class but I modified it to show you how to pass in those search properties in a new instance of a control.
I have not confirmed that this code works, its more like a concept. I omitted null checks etc. to make the example more clear:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.WpfControls;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Example
{
    public class Sample : UITestControl
    {
        public Sample(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) :
                base(searchLimitContainer)
        {
            #region Search Criteria
            this.SearchProperties[WpfControl.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "Foo";
            this.SearchProperties[WpfControl.PropertyNames.AutomationId] = "Bar";
            #endregion
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a control with user defined searchproperties using a existing control from e.g. the UIMap.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="searchLimitContainer">your control.</param>
        /// <param name="searchPropList">List of properties needed to find the control on your UI.</param>
        public Sample(UITestControl searchLimitContainer, params KeyValuePair<PropertyExpression, string>[] searchPropList) :
                base(searchLimitContainer)
        {
            foreach (var keyValuePairItem in searchPropList)
            {
                this.SearchProperties.Single(sp => sp == keyValuePairItem.Key).PropertyValue = keyValuePairItem.Value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You should be able to use it like this:

```
UITestControl ControlName = new Sample(AllUIMaps.ClientMaps.TopBars.Window.Screen, searchPropList)
```

Not sure you can actually change the UIMap, it's generated code